# how to run and monitor a python script in a azure virtual machine using python

Tags: python, azure, automation, data-science, virtual-machine

I am trying to start a Azure virtual machine and run a python script using a bat file inside the VM, monitor it and power off the VM if the batch process is terminated, using python

I have figured out the way to shut down and start the VM, is there a any method, library to run a batch file and to monitor it using python

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do monitoring by python `subprocess` module.

Also you can [check microsoft offical documentation of Batch job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python)

You can try this type code:

```
import subprocess
import select

# batch file
batch_file_path = 'path/to/batch/file.bat'
process = subprocess.Popen(batch_file_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Monitor the status
while True:
    # Wait for output
    streams = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [], [], 1.0)[0]
    for stream in streams:
        output = stream.readline()
        if output:
            print(output.strip().decode())

    # Check if the process
    if process.poll() is not None:
        break

if process.returncode == 0:
    # Your code to shutdown the Azure VM
    pass
else:
    # Your code to handle error
    pass
```